# Encoding a Javascript string to EBCDIC (MQPut)

Tags: javascript, ibm-mq, mainframe

I have a javascript application which I use to do MQPut on a MQ queue on a mainframe. It works well, except that newline characters do not get encoded correctly...

Did some research and realised I probably need to convert the message/string into IBM cp278 which is the Swedish and Finnish EBCDIC encoding/format, before doing the put...

**So i tried something like:**

```
import cptable from 'codepage';  // https://github.com/SheetJS/js-codepage
let message = 'This is a mq message \nThis is the second line';
let buf =  cptable.utils.encode(1143, message); // 1143 in codepage = cp278
encoded_message = buf.toString();
console.log(encoded_message);
```

The console.log(encoded_message) outputs some gibberish similar to: 143, 567, 543, 678 ... and so on

and then the mqput:

```
  var msg = encoded_message;
  var mqmd = new mq.MQMD(); 
  mqmd.CodedCharSetId = 278;
  var pmo = new mq.MQPMO();

  pmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT |
                MQC.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID |
                MQC.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID;

  ghObj = hObj;
  return mq.PutPromise(hObj,mqmd,pmo,msg);
```

When I look on the mainframe it looks like message never was encoded correctly, and it looks exactly like the console.log (143, 567, 543, 678 ...)

Any ideas on how to correctly encode a string in JS to cp278 before put on a mq queue?
Quite sure I'm missing something crucial here ...

Comment: Have a read? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=services-writing-data-conversion-exits

Comment: I did, any particular you had in mind?

Comment: Perhaps you can get the MQ to covert from utf8: MQGMO_CONVERT https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=queue-application-data-conversion

Disclaimer: I have not sent data to a mainframe for at least 15 years and that was not using MQ

Comment: Its a good idea... But unfortunately there is also a bug for newlines on cp278, so after I've somehow managed to encode it into cp278 I also need to replace the byte representation of the new line, before doing the put.
Thanks for the effort!

Comment: If you found a fix, post a self answer.

Comment: @JoshMc no problem, I will... Currently considering trying to call a python function for the conversion...

Comment: Looks like this question was also raised on the GitHub repo for the Node.js wrapper libraries for MQI  - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/issues/158